ESLint recognizes Vue Component as type?
I just implemented following rule to my eslint:
'@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': 'error',
Everything works fine, unless In components where I do something like this:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import BasicModal from '@/components/BasicComponents/BasicModal.vue';

const modal = ref<InstanceType<typeof BasicModal>>();
...

Here I use BasicModal in the modal ref to infer some of the exposed functions and so on (I obviously also use it as a Component here) ...
Since I enabled, I get errors like these:
[client] 41:1 error All imports in the declaration are only used as types. Use `import type` u/typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78749166/4378314

I'm not sure if the link is related, it's more like eslint may have problems with script setup syntax. It's not shown whether BasicModal is used in a template. A workaround would be  importing it twice, import type TBasicModal ...; import BasicModal .... But this is fundamental problem with script setup. It's not JS but a magical DSL without a strict spec

maybe you can try the new useTemplateRef(BasicModal) instead of InstanceType<typeof>
